# JavaFX change color of text when TEXT in a list-cell is highlighted

Tags: css, user-interface, javafx

In a CSS style-sheet in JavaFX can I add a style class that allows the color of the text to be changed when the mouse actually hovers on the text itself instead of just the list-view cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```css
.list-cell .text {
    /* Default value: */
    -fx-fill: -fx-text-background-color ;
}

.list-cell .text:hover {
    -fx-fill: yellow ;
}
```

Note the `.text` style class does not seem to be documented.

Comment: Dude, I thought I tried this, but I must have missed something... I freaking love you thanks. I'm so dumb.